# Graph Algo to find Closest Connection

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, graph-algorithm

I have a dataset which logs each shift an employee has worked. For each employee, I'd like to find the coworker they've worked with the most.

The table has ~250M rows, with 50M shifts and 100K unique employees. To give you an example, the table starts like:

```
+----------+--------+
| Shift ID | Emp ID |  
+----------+--------+
|        1 | A      |  
|        1 | B      |  
|        2 | A      |
|        2 | C      | 
|        3 | A      |  
|        3 | C      |
+----------+--------+
```

Employee A has worked with Employee B once but with employee C twice. So Employee A's most frequent coworker is Employee C.

What algorithm can find each employee's most frequent coworker? Naively trying to find find the number of pairwise common shifts was too slow:

```
solution = {}
for e in employees:
    maxCommonShifts = 0
    for c in employees:
        if e != c:
            commonTrips = len(e.trips ∩ c.trips)
            if commonTrips > maxCommonShifts:
                maxCommonShifts = commonTrips
                solution[e] = c
```

I believe a graph algo would be the solution here. Specifically, this problem seems analogous to FB trying to calculate a person's closest friend in the sense they have the most mutual friends. In terms of the graph, there would be one node for each shift and one node for each employee. Each employee node is connected to each shift node they've worked.

Answer (score 1):

250M rows with 50M shifts gives you an average of 5 rows per shift, so creating a set of records for each shift giving the pairs of employees in that shift would increase your data size by a factor of something over 5, which is expensive but not too awful. So your first shift, seeing 1A and 1B, would create two records recording the pairs AB and BA. If you had 1A, 1B, and 1C then you would create records AB, AC, BA, BC, CA, CB.

With input in this format you can do what you want using small programs and sort utilities (unix and windows both have sort programs) or using SQL in a database. Sort the list of perhaps 2000M pairs generated by first member and then second member. Then process down this list sequentially. You will see the records sorted into order such as AB AB AB AC AC AD AD AD AD AE AE... and you can pick out the runs of identical records and count them, keeping track of the longest such run for each first element of a pair as you come across it.

Comment: For my particular use case, this will work - thanks! Out of curiosity, is there a more scalable algorithm? Your approach scales the dataset by a factor of N^2 where N is # of employees per shift. For example, if there were 100 employees per shift, this would scale the table by factor of 100*99=9900 which is doable on a decent computer cluster. But if the number of employees per shift is 150, 160, ... and so approach becomes too expensive.

Comment: I am not aware of a more scalable algorithm and a quick search round did not find one - but I am no expert. My starting points were https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Count%E2%80%93min_sketch (solves some storage problems but still (N choose 2) pairs if N people on a shift) and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apriori_algorithm (tells me that I can discard workers known to work very few shifts, but I don't regard that as a breakthrough here).